# Can't grap elements in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a Selenium script to export data from my homebanking account.

However, when I reach the login screen I'm facing some difficulties grapping the correct elements in order to input my credentials.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

This is my code so far:
I have commented the locations where I'm in trouble.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(str('https://www.lsb.dk/login'))

# close cookies popup
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'coi-banner__decline'))).click()

# click button to log in
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Log på med MitID')]")
for btn in buttons:
    try:
        btn.click()
    except:
        pass

# From this point I have difficulties:
# Wait for the input field to load.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='username7']")))

# Try to input my username (This doesn't work)
driver.find_elements((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='username7']")).send_keys('My usename')

# Try to locate the "Fortsæt" button
buttons1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Fortsæt')]")

# Click the "Fortsæt" button when found
for btn in buttons1:
    try:
        btn.click()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What is happening? It will be useful if you provide html structure as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  You mean like the html sourcecode? Or the whole mess that pops up when I inspect the page? Due to IT security (I think), I can't link further in to the code than the www.lsb.dk/login, but from there you need to click "log på med mitID" and inspect from there.